# Unstyle element

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have several material design components in my app, but for 2 input elements, I want to override the material design style.

How to remove the CSS style from a `<input matInput>` element,
that is looks like an unstyled text input element?

Comment: Can you modify the markup and not give it the `matInput` attribute?

Comment: maybe, but I use a date picker on that element, when I omit it: ```mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. Did you forget to add matInput to the native input or textarea element?```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

My code was:

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput  [matDatepicker]="picker1" (click)="picker1.open()" >
          <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

which needed the `matInput`, to omit it, I removed the form field:

```
<input [matDatepicker]="picker1" (click)="picker1.open()" >
<mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
```